# How should I remove Rambler from Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am having one problem in my chrome browser, whenever I search for anything it search from Rambler but the default search engine is Google, by the way i have also searched for 'how to remove Rambler' but unfortunately not works..
Anyone please suggest me what to do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to reset Google Chrome or a fresh installation? It should help as far as you remove it completly (not just a reinstall that keeps all the settings).